# Droid RAZR MAXX encryption downgrades max camera resolution

Tags: camera, motorola-droid, encryption, motorola-droid-razr

After submitting my DROID RAZR MAXX to the whims of my company's OLA for getting access to work mail, calendar, and contacts, it was encrypted, including the storage.  Encryption notified me, before proceeding, that my HD video recording resolution would be downgraded from 1080p to 720.  Sure enough, after it was complete, the max video recording resolution option was "DVD (720 x480)".  However, my front-facing camera can still do 720p.

Was this documented anywhere? Or is this something an ActiveSync admin can push? This cuaght me by surprise.

Answer (score 1):

It is the result of encryption, unfortunately I cannot find any documentation.

My device (Razr) showed the same message when I enabled device encryption on setup, before I had any ActiveSync accounts added.

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://forums.androidcentral.com/droid-razr-maxx/165597-video-downgrade-after-encryption.html#post1689036) forum post suggests that it may be related to your company policy.

If not, it could be that some of the camera hardware could be used for encryption, however that is highly unlikely.